# how to add tools.jar as a "dynamic dependency" in sbt. is it possible?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, tools.jar

i need to use tools.jar in my project, but there is not much sense to package it in the jar, since the user already have it. so, is it possible to use it as a "dynamic dependency"? meaning, i want my code to **compile** by using `tools.jar` file found in **my** `JAVA_HOME`, but i don't want it to get packaged with it. i can make sure to add it to the classpath with double activation at runtime with the **user's** `JAVA_HOME` used instead. for example:

```
object Main1 extends App {
    val myjar = Main1.getClass.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation.getFile
    val tools = System.getProperty("java.home").dropRight(3)+"lib/tools.jar" // drop "jre"
    val arguments = Array("java", "-cp", myjar+":"+tools, "me.myapp.Main2") ++ args
    val p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(arguments)
    p.getErrorStream.close
    p.getOutputStream.close
}
```

FYI: i packge the app using assembly plugin in a standalone jar file.

**EDIT:**

an ugly solution would be to copy the `tools.jar` file to a lib directory in my project, and add:

```
excludedJars in assembly <<= (fullClasspath in assembly) map { cp => 
    cp filter {_.data.getName == "tools.jar"}
}
```

in `build.sbt`
can it be done more elegantly, without copying the jar file? would be much more easier to switch JVMs, and use the "right" `tools.jar` file automatically...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after reading more carefully the [SBT Documentation](http://www.devdaily.com/downloads/scala/Scala-SBT-Documentation.pdf), i found out how to do this:
in `build.sbt` i needed to add:

```
// adding the tools.jar to the unmanaged-jars seq
unmanagedJars in Compile ~= {uj => 
    Seq(Attributed.blank(file(System.getProperty("java.home").dropRight(3)+"lib/tools.jar"))) ++ uj
}

// exluding the tools.jar file from the build
excludedJars in assembly <<= (fullClasspath in assembly) map { cp => 
    cp filter {_.data.getName == "tools.jar"}
}
```

and that's about it... simple as that :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an sbt plugin to do this for you now: https://github.com/chipsenkbeil/sbt-jdi-tools

Comment: This plugin simply adds the dependency.
The question (quite old by now, and predates the plugin by a few years) asks how to compile against `tools.jar` without adding it to the packaged app. The problem with `tools.jar` is that it *should* match the runtime java. It does'nt matter which JDK was used to compile the program, the JDK you run it on may be different, and you'll want to add the `tools.jar` dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this, but could you not use the % configuration syntax to only map the dependency into runtime or compile? surely tools.jar should be automatically included anyway?

```
libraryDependencies += "com.sun" % "tools" % "1.6.0" % system
```

I'm not sure about the "system" configuration, I know this works in maven, you could try this with "compile" instead though.

Comment: iv'e allready tried it... (BTW, it's `"system"` not `system`). i get this error:
`[error] {file:/home/gilad/workspace_eclipse/app-using-tools/}root/*:update: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add dependency 'com.sun#tools;1.6.0' to configuration 'system' of module me.myapp#app-using-tools_2.9.2;0.1 because this configuration doesn't exist!
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 15, 2012 7:54:45 PM`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @giladhoch. As I did mention, I wasn't sure about the `system` configuration, and suggested testing with `compile` or `runtime` configurations to see if that works.

Comment: the right configuration would be `"provided"`, but it would not work either since tools.jar isn't published to any maven repo (though you could publish to a private repo). And besides, you would want to run against a code matching the runtime java. So using `unmanagedJars` is the right solution here.