# Sbt always does full rebuild because of modified binary dependency rt.jar

Tags: scala, sbt

Sbt always does full rebuild because of modified binary dependency: rt.jar:

```
[debug] 
[debug] Initial source changes: 
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] Modified external sources: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\rt.jar)
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
```

Obviously, rt.jar wasn't changed, its created/accesses/modified dates are the same and quite old.

It's in c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\

JAVA_HOME is set as C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_37

JAVA_HOME/bin is in PATH.

Any ideas why sbt thinks rt.jar was changed?

Comment: I am getting this too, in this case with /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jce.jar

Comment: This may or may not be the case for you, but often for me when SBT decides to be retarded, I just need to restart it for it to come to its senses.

Comment: Is there a chance that you run two instances of SBT with different JDKs? I know this happened to me; I was running one from idea-sbt-plugin and one from the command line.

Comment: Unlikely. I start single sbt session with the same JDK and do "package" 5 times in a row with the same result(Modified binary dependencies: Set(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\rt.jar)). I tried it even after my pc restart.

Comment: Somewhere here:
    def externalBinaryModified(entry: String => Option[File], analysis: File => Option[Analysis], previous: Stamps, current: ReadStamps)(implicit equivS: Equiv[Stamp]): File => Boolean =
  dependsOn =>
   analysis(dependsOn).isEmpty &&
   orTrue(
    for {
     name <- previous.className(dependsOn)
     e <- entry(name)
    } yield {
     val resolved = Locate.resolve(e, name)
     (resolved != dependsOn) || !equivS.equiv(previous.binary(dependsOn), current.binary(resolved))
    }
   )

Comment: as a workaround you can do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409847/how-to-add-tools-jar-as-a-dynamic-dependency-in-sbt-is-it-possible). exclude it from the build (temporarily...), and invoke your program with `rt.jar` added to classpath... just remember to include it back in the build for release...

Comment: reported issue: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/issues/583

Comment: I've created a pull request that fixed the issue and it was merged recently. Thanks, Mark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had JAVA_HOME set to C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_37 and sbt resolved the dependency as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\rt.jar. Sbt uses java.io.File.equals() which is not correct in this case:

In sbt/compile/inc/Incremental.scala:

```
def externalBinaryModified(entry: String => Option[File], analysis: File => Option[Analysis], previous: Stamps, current: ReadStamps)(implicit equivS: Equiv[Stamp]): File => Boolean =
    dependsOn =>
        analysis(dependsOn).isEmpty &&
        orTrue(
            for {
                name <- previous.className(dependsOn)
                _ = println("Name: " + name)
                e <- entry(name)
                _ = println("entry: " + e)
            } yield {
                val resolved = Locate.resolve(e, name)
                println("resolved: " + resolved)
                println("dependsOn: " + dependsOn)
                println("resolved != dependsOn: " + (resolved != dependsOn))
                (resolved != dependsOn) || !equivS.equiv(previous.binary(dependsOn), current.binary(resolved))
            }
        )
```

gives the following output:

```
Name: java.lang.Object
entry: c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\rt.jar
resolved: c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\rt.jar
dependsOn: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\rt.jar
resolved != dependsOn: true
```

Thus, sbt always thinks rt.jar was changed.

Workaround would be setting JAVA_HOME to "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37"
Solution would be to do:

```
resolved.getCanonicalPath != dependsOn.getCanonicalPath
```